# Parallel Computing-output each process to file

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, output

I have a function that I would like to compute for several values in parallel and for each computation, I would like to save the output to its own file.

I am currently trying to use the multiprocessing package in order to make this a parallel process, but I am new to using this and perhaps I am not using it correctly. (I am uncertain about the use of Pool vs Process classes) Also, I know how to print my output using the bash command below. This is in essence a problem about how to implement parallel computing and outputting the results to txt files.

Here is a toy example that I am currently working with:
I have this function save in a file called test.py

```
def fcn(n):
    c = int(n*(n-1)/2)
    print('My output will print several things like this code')
    print(c)
    return
```

Normally when I write the output of a function to a file, I use the bash command

```
python test.py > output.txt
```

For parallel computing, the sample code that I have would something that writes each output to an element in a list, but it does not write the output to a file, which is what I would like. (My actual problem will have a lot stored in memory if I keep all outputs stored as elements of a list like this. I would like it to just write to a file and move on to the next computation)

```
import multiprocessing as mp

pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
results = [pool.apply(fcn,args = n, for n in range(6)]
pool.close()
```

The output I would like to have is 6 different txt files with the outputs of fcn(n) for n=0,1,2,3,4,5 for each one. Each of the files I would like to be named after the input, for example 0.txt,1.txt, etc, if possible. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You could use the `logging` module to give each process a separate output file... https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html

Comment: @MarkSetchell The logging module provides outputs that are prefaced by 'WARNING:root' or 'INFO:root', so is this possible to remove? How is it different from just open('filename.txt','w') and writing to that?

Comment: Mark's proposal was smart in that it can "collect" outputs from different reporting agents and store 'em into one log, without user having to solve how to recollect details from many concurrently running reporting agents. Your use-case, as defined above, is slightly different. You insisted on using one separate file per each process to store "individual" results separately. Logging module is cute for cases where hundreds and thousands of reporting agents flood the central log with many uncoordinated details, yet the log is kept nice and tidy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my response here: [Multiprocessing for Pandas Dataframe write to excel sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57340783/multiprocessing-for-pandas-dataframe-write-to-excel-sheets/57341121#57341121)

This idea is to create writer worker and pipe results through `multiprocessing.Queue`. (this idea is needed when you would like to put all responses in single nontrivial, like excel, file format)

Other solution is to write to separated files:

```py
def fcn(n):
    c = int(n*(n-1)/2)
    with open("file{}.txt".format(n), 'w') as ff:
        ff.write('My output will print several things like this code\n')
        ff.write(str(c)+'\n')
    return
```

Comment: With all respect, adding Queue into the simplest ever Multiprocessing workflow ( using as trivial strategy as the fire-and-forget ) is an overkill - both design-wise and the performance-wise ( each Queue operation comes at double cost - serialise/marshall/enQueue + deQueue/deserialise/yield, before the object gets delivered just one way into one of the Multiprocessing processes.

Comment: Thank you! Either of these solutions would be perfect, however, I will opt for the second one of having the function write to separate files rather than have a Queue to pipe results through. Initially, I was trying to do this and have all results on one file, but I believe this will be easier for me to implement as I am inexperienced with the Multiprocessing package!

Comment: On linux you can easy contaminate files with  `cat file1 file2 file3 > out_file`

Answer (score 1):

> **Q** : *...would like to save the output to its own file.*

### For the sake of simplicity, let's do it simple & a bit safer :

Given the task, each of the running processes is independent from any other and has its own, exclusively owned file-I/O directed to a "private", numbered or otherwise differentiated file.

Just may add a few SLOC-s, using a **`with`**`... as aFile:` context-enclosed file-I/O and most probably a few `try:/except:/finally:` handling sections for cases something wrong happens on the fly:

```
def fcn( n ):
    try:                                                               #.________
        with open( "aFileFromPROC[{0:}].txt".format( n ), "w" ) as aF: #| context
             ...do.whatever.needed...                            # aF  #|
             aF.write(...)                                       # aF  #|
             ...do.whatever.needed...                            # aF  #|
             aF.write(...)                                       # aF  #|
             ...do.whatever.needed...                            # aF  #|
             aF.write(...)                                       # aF  #|
             pass                                                # aF  #|________
    except:
        ...
    finally:
        ...
        return
```

Comment: Thank you! This also works for me! Much appreciated!